# MediaElement slow seek loading

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

For reasons I cannot understand likely due to my limited knowledge of the internals of these controls, the MediaElement control takes a linearly increasing amount of time to load when the amount of time skipped increases when loading a video from a URL.

For example, skipping ahead 30 seconds on the video will take a brief second to load. However, skipping 30 minutes ahead in the video can take upwards of 30-40 seconds to load. The playback state changed event is never fired and the control freezes ignoring any transforms.

1. This issue does not appear to occur when buffering has reached that point in the video
2. This issue happens using the default transport controls and also while settings the position value manually (likely due to transport controls doing just that internally)
3. This issue happens with all file types with all types of common encoding methods that I know of (H264, H265, VP9, MP4V).
4. I have not tested if this issue persists with local videos. However, I doubt this would be relevant information.

   ```
    viewer.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, viewer.Position.Seconds + 600);
    // Delay occurs after a reasonable skip (in this situation 10 minutes)
   ```

I would greatly appreciate help on coming up with a solution to get around this issue.

Comment: I tried to play a video using MediaElement, but after it loaded, it can play quickly, I can skip to any position in a brief time. Whether it is the video file's issue? Could you have a try with other media files? Or can you provide a repro sample?

Comment: I tried different encoding methods such as H264, H265, VP9, MP4V. I also tried MP4, AAC, and WebM files with no change.

Comment: What is your app target version and min version and your device OS version? Can you see the issue in the latest windows version(17134)?